# Does UWP need .NET/.NET Core To Run On Client?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, uwp, package-managers

I have looked for this everywhere but cannot understand what to do.

I understand that UWP apps need their dependencies installed, but do they also need .Net/.Net Core installed on the client machine?

What I am doing:
Using another UWP app and the `PackageManager` class, I am making my own installer. (UWP installs UWP)

So I know I will have to install the dependencies (`appx` files) too, but do I also have to make sure that .Net/.Net Core is installed? Thanks!

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Ok. Thanks! Current windows means windows 10 right? Well it doesn't matter because that is all I am targeting!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but do they also need .Net/.Net Core installed on the client machine?

No. A UWP app targets a natively implemented SDK version that doesn't have any dependency on .NET Core.

The C# language projection is indeed based on .NET but the CoreCLR (.NET Core runtime) is not used at runtime so you don't have to install any addtional .NET stuff on the client machines where your UWP app is run.

Comment: So I wouldn't have to install the dependencies? Just the appx for the actual app? Thanks!

Comment: @admin: Yes, just the APPX package.